# How can I move a value of variable html to a file/child component vue?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

My code is works. The code like this :

```
<template>
    ...
</template>

<script>

export default {
    methods: { 
        setFooter () {
            if (!this.footer) {
                const div = document.createElement('div')
                let html

                html = "\
                <span>\
                    <div style='float:left; height: 14px; width: 14px; border-radius: 12px;'>\
                    </div>\
                </span>\
                <span style='float: left;font-size:12px'>Available</span>\
                <span>\
                    <div style='float:left;height: 14px; width: 14px; border-radius: 12px;'>\
                    </div>\
                </span>\
                <span style='float:left; font-size: 12px'>Not available</span>"

                div.innerHTML = html
                document.querySelector('.v-date-picker-table').append(div)
                this.footer = true
            }
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

setFooter method called if an asynchronous/Axios done

My problem is that my code looks sloppy and unreadable. Because I store the HTML tag inside the HTML variable. So I want to move it into a file/component Vue. Maybe I should call a child component of a method

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!-- footer.vue   -->

<template>
  <div>
      footer code
  </div>
</template>


   

<script>


export default {
 props:["myvalue"]
   }
</script>
 


<!-- main.vue   -->


<template>
  <div>
      <footer :myvalue="myvalue"></footer>
  </div>
</template>


<script>

import footer from "footer.vue"

export default {
  components:{footer},
  data(){
      return {
       myvalue:"data"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's what I meant. try reading my question well

Comment: please check it now

Comment: it does not help. please update according to my case

Comment: This is exactly what you're asking for! A Vue component which is imported into another component.

Answer (score 0):

How I've read OP's question...

When some async call completed, we need to put some HTML into some external DOM element which is not under control of the current VueJS app.

I would suggest using [Portal](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/portal-a-new-feature-in-vue-3/) for VueJS 3 or some 3rd Party lib providing similar functionality.

Using Portal you can inject active VueJS component into foreign DOM element. Also, you will be able to import a shared VueX store or some other state storage and react to the completion of async call in parallel with the main orchestrator component of the VueJS app.

I hope it'll do the job...

Comment: I am confused for that implementation. It doesn't seem to fit my case. For my case, I just want to store the value of the html variable in a file / component. But my problem is I'm confused how do I call the file / component

Comment: I understand your point.. You just want to extract this HTML into separate resource.
But I expect going this way you may face with a lot of additional problems (it is harder to edit plain text HTML without IDE support).
Moving regular Vue component into foreign DOM element will be more agile. You will be able to place your HTML there and edit it as you do with other components.
Also, learning Portals is a must for modern developer,

If you want simplistic solution... just save this HTML into separate file on the server, load it with ajax/axios as text and put into innerHtml.

Answer (score 0):

The existing implementation looks fine. The primary thing you are trying to achieve is to move the unreadable HTML code to a separate component and mount dynamically to the current component when the date picker is opened.

It won't work in that way.The Child component cannot be mounted into a parent datepicker component. Because,

```
document.querySelector('.v-date-picker-table').append(div)
```

The old above logic appends HTML string to a div element, datepicker component is dynamically created on the fly, you won't have control to append another Vue component

Instead, you can store HTML string to a separate js file to make your code readable

> // create a js file names utility.js(any file name to your convenient)

```
'use strict'
let getFooterDiv = function() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var html = "<span><div style='float:left;height: 20px; width: 20px; border-radius: 10px; background-color: green;'></div></span><span style='margin-left: 10px; float: left;'>Available</span><span><div style='float:left;height: 20px; width: 20px; border-radius: 10px; background-color: black; margin-left:10px;'></div></span><span style='margin-left: 10px; float:left;'>Unavailable</span>";
  div.innerHTML = html;
  return div;
}; 
module.exports = {
  footerDiv: getFooterDiv,
}
```

> in the above component you can import this js function and use it

```
    import { footerDiv } from utility;


.....

    setFooter() {
      if (!this.footer) {
        var footer = footerDiv();
        document.querySelector('.v-date-picker-table').append(footer);
        this.footer = true;
      }
    },
```

**Now the code looks readable, and html generation is moved to a separate function instead of separate component**